# iOS8 Custom Keyboard using Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, ios8, xcode6

Anyone know how to create a custom iOS keyboard in Xcode6 using storyboards? I've built a keyboard fully using code using a single application template. It works fine, but I want to build another keyboard using storyboards as I think it will be easier.

Can't figure out how to connect a storyboard to the KeyboardViewController.m? Anyone know how, and a set of steps to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Yes it's absolutely possible.
Once you created your target extension, right click and add a New Storyboard. Inside this storyboard, you must define the Custom Class as a KeyboardViewController.

Then, one thing is missing: you should add `NSExtensionMainStoryboard` with the name of your freshly created storyboard without the extension in the `NSExtensionAttributes` of your extension `info.plist` file and remove the `NSExtensionMainClass` property from it.

A little clean and run and voilà! A keyboard that use a storyboard!
Hope that will help!

Comment: It seems there is no NSExtensionMainClass but only NSExtensionPrincipalClass, so this doesn't really work for me. :/

Comment: I deleted NSExtensionPrincipalClass instead of NSExtensionMainClass and this worked. I didn't find a reference to NSExtensionMainClass in Apple's docs.

Answer (score 9):

Under the extension, inside the `info.plist` file, under `NSExtension` Dictionary, add a new item called `NSExtensionMainStoryboard`, set the name according to your storyboard name, and then remove the `NSExtensionPrincipalClass`.

Note: tested in Xcode 6.4, using Swift.

Comment: At the same time please make sure: added a button calling self.advanceToNextInputMode() and set the "Storyboard Entry Point" otherwise the keyboard can't be launched