# iOS custom keyboard with storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, keyboard

I'm trying to make a simple iOS custom keyboard extension using Swift. The default UIView wasn't meeting my needs, so I read on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979693/ios8-custom-keyboard-using-storyboards) SO question that I could use a storyboard with the `NSExtensionMainStoryboard` property in `info.plist`.

Unfortunately every time I open my keyboard, I get the following errors

```
2016-01-18 18:02:56.350 Kappa Keyboard[44790:2959180] Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 44787: (null)
2016-01-18 18:02:56.368 Kappa Keyboard[44790:2959138] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x002f1746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01d32a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x001a6ce1 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 881
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x001a6941 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 65
    4   UIKit                               0x00c7d0bd -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:] + 417
    5   UIKit                               0x00c968aa -[UIViewController(UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods) addChildViewController:] + 78
    6   UIKit                               0x01206db8 -[_UIViewServiceViewControllerOperator __createViewController:withContextToken:fbsDisplays:appearanceSerializedRepresentations:legacyAppearance:traitCollection:initialInterfaceOrientation:hostAccessibilityServerPort:canShowTextServices:replyHandler:] + 2702
```

The stack trace continues on, but that's the gist of it.

Here's all I've done (I tried this in a clean project).

1. Create container app
2. Create Keyboard target
3. Add Main.storyboard
4. Add `NSExtension.NSExtensionMainStoryboard: Main` to info.plist
5. Set `Main.storyboard`'s custom class to the default `KeyboardViewController`

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a storyboard file to your keyboard target.
In your keyboard target's general tab, make `Main Interface` to your storyboard file like in the screenshot.
The second important part is making sure to change your `KeyboardViewController` reference's view's class to `UIInputView` instead of `UIView` in storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have built a custom keyboard app too.
Here are the steps:

**Objective-C**

1. create a keyboard target
2. create a xib file in target bundle (MyKeyboard.xib)
3. create cocoa touch class select UIView (MyKeyboard.h MyKeyboard.m)
4. inside KeyboardViewController.m, import MyKeyboard.h
5. inside KeyboardViewController.m, add

---

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyKeyboard *myKeyboard;
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
self.myKeyboard = [[MyKeyboard alloc]init];
self.myKeyboard = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibName: @"MyKeyboard"
                                     owner:self option:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
self.inputView = (UIInputView *)self.myKeyboard;
```

---

**Swift**

1. create a keyboard target
2. create a UIView interface (xib file) in target bundle (MyKeyboard.xib)
3. create cocoa touch class select UIInputView (MyKeyboard.swift)
4. inside KeyboardViewController.swift add

// here

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // setup your keyboard
    self.myKeyboard = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyKeyboard", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! MyKeyboard
    self.inputView = self.myKeyboard;

    // Perform custom UI setup here
    self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .System)
    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Next Keyboard", comment: "Title for 'Next Keyboard' button"), forState: .Normal)
    self.nextKeyboardButton.sizeToFit()
    self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: "advanceToNextInputMode", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.myKeyboard.addSubview(self.nextKeyboardButton) // add the button to self.myKeyboard!!

    let nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    self.view.addConstraints([nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint, nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint])
}
```

Here is what it'll look like
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your thoroughness but I'm looking for a storyboard-based keyboard, not a .xib file.